# Why PowerShell opens a new window when running exe

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-prompt

I have a PowerShell script like this:

```
$tfExe = path/to/tf.exe

& $tfExt ... do something
```

On my computer (and other PCs) if I run this script I get the .exe output in my PowerShell window.

When I run the script on another computer (with Windows 7 32-bit) it opens a cmd window, the output displayed there, and the window is immediately closed.

The issue occurs for each .exe tool, even in `robocopy`.

Why does this happen and how can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another issue with my PowerShell and the solution to that issue also solved this issue.

In my `PATHEXT` environment variable I didn't have `.exe`.  When I added it, the issue solved and all the .exe tools ran smoothly and the output appears in the PowerShell window.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and figured out I had deleted the folder I was executing the commands from.

PATHEXT was ok:
[image]

But this was not (I had deleted it outside of PowerShell - oops):
[image]

Navigating to another path solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting an external exe, so it's working as intended. You could however try using cmd.exe /K - more info here https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

Comment: If you follow the link, there is an option to:/K     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
          This is useful for testing, to examine variables

So my /c was a bit missleading ;)

Comment: In many computers I got the exe output in my PowerShell and any windowd doesn't open, only in specific computer it occurs. I assume the issue is in the specific computer and not in the others.

Comment: Yes - depending on OS there are various ways (registry) to change the behaviour of the windows command proc.

Comment: That doesn't exactly make sense.  When i run &"MSBuild.exe" it doesn't create a new window, but when i run &"SonarScanner.MSBuild.Exe" it does.  it want to trap the output not open in a new cmd window.